# Is HTML5 = HTML + CSS + Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

While reading some article I came across a statement which says :

**HTML5 = HTML + CSS + Javascript**

**Is it Correct to Say So..?**

Till now I thought HTML5 is just another (although much better) version Of HTML and CSS & JS are separate.

Comment: This image explains all https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5#/media/File:HTML5_APIs_and_related_technologies_taxonomy_and_status.svg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Html + CSS + JavaScript used to be called DHTML.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_HTML

HTML5 itself is a markup language.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5

Answer (score 4):

No, HTML5 is the latest version of HTML and that's it.

It does not imply:

- CSS version
- Whether it's XML compliant
- Whether javascript is used
- anything else other than the HTML used is version 5

All it means is that the HTML used is version 5.

Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 2):

No, HTML5 does not include JS or CSS as one of its attributes. HTML 5 is an expansion on previous HTML versions which allows the use of **[new HTML elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not the case.

**HTML5** is a markup language used for structuring and presenting content on the World Wide Web. It was finalized, and published, on 28 October 2014 by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C). This is the fifth revision of the HTML standard since the inception of the World Wide Web.

[More info](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/H/HTML5.html)